# I want to upload files into a table in sqlserver please assist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to read files from a path and upload the data into a table using a .fmt file but some file are failing to upload with error "Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)""

My sql code is there and my fmt file is as below

```
            DECLARE @RowCnt int, @filename varchar(256), @filenumber int,  @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

            --Create the table to store file list
            CREATE TABLE #myFileList (FileNumber INT IDENTITY,FileName VARCHAR(256))
            CREATE TABLE #FileStatus (FileNumber INT ,FileName VARCHAR(256), status varchar(255))
            --Insert file list from directory to SQL Server
            DECLARE @Path varchar(256) = 'C:\TEMP\2019\8Aug2019\'
            DECLARE @Path1 varchar(256) = 'dir ' + @Path
            DECLARE @Command varchar(1024) =  @Path1 + ' /A-D  /B'
            INSERT INTO #myFileList
            EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_cmdshell @Command


            DECLARE FileList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
            FOR SELECT FileNumber, FileName from #myFileList -- WHERE FileNumber in (1,2,3,4,5)
            --FOR select SvrName, SvrStatus from SQLDBMAIL.DBO.LSvrTable
            OPEN FileList

            FETCH NEXT FROM FileList INTO @filenumber, @filename

            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
            BEGIN

             begin try
              SET @sql =  N' INSERT INTO OBITABLE
                             SELECT A.RECTYPE, A.RECNO, A.ACCTNO, A.AMOUNT,
                            A.DRCR, A.EFFDATE, A.REFERENCE, A.BOTRANTYPE,
                            A.FETRANTYPE, A.TRANPLACE, A.CARDNO,
                            A.ISOTERMID, A.ISOMERCHID, A.RETREFNO,
                            A.ACQBIN
                            from OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @Path +@filename+ ''',
                            FORMATFILE = ''C:\TEMP\OBIBackup\OBIFMT.fmt'',
                            FIRSTROW = 1) AS A WHERE [RECTYPE]=''RCTP10'''

                    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

               insert into #FileStatus
               select @filenumber, @filename,'OK'
             end try 
             begin catch
               insert into #FileStatus
               select @filenumber, @filename,ERROR_MESSAGE()+'ERROR'
             end catch

            FETCH NEXT FROM FileList INTO @filenumber, @filename
            END
            CLOSE FileList
            DEALLOCATE FileList

            select * from #FileStatus where status like '%ERROR'

            DROP TABLE #myFileList
            GO

            DROP TABLE #FileStatus
            GO
```

/* FMT FILE */

```
10.0
25
1   SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      1   RECTYPE     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
2   SQLCHAR 0   12  ""      2   RECNO       SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
3   SQLCHAR 0   32  ""      3   ACCTNO      SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
4   SQLCHAR 0   9   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
5   SQLCHAR 0   12  ""      4   AMOUNT      ""
6   SQLCHAR 0   2   ""      5   DRCR        SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
7   SQLCHAR 0   4   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
8   SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      6   EFFDATE     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
9   SQLCHAR 0   1   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
10  SQLCHAR 0   16  ""      7   REFERENCE   SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
11  SQLCHAR 0   1   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
12  SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      8   BOTRANTYPE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
13  SQLCHAR 0   37  ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
14  SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      9   FETRANTYPE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
15  SQLCHAR 0   1   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
16  SQLCHAR 0   40  ""      10  TRANPLACE   SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
17  SQLCHAR 0   32  ""      11  CARDNO      SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
18  SQLCHAR 0   236 ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
19  SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      12  ISOTERMID   SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
20  SQLCHAR 0   15  ""      13  ISOMERCHID  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
21  SQLCHAR 0   8   ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
22  SQLCHAR 0   12  ""      14  RETREFNO    SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
23  SQLCHAR 0   16  ""      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
24  SQLCHAR 0   6   ""      15  ACQBIN      SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
25  SQLCHAR 0   141 "\r\n"      0   BlankFl     SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
```

Comment: `PRINT` (or `SELECT`) the value of your dynamic SQL and inspect and debug that first. Then apply that fix to your code above. We can't run your SQL, so we can't replicate your problem, nor can we see the actual SQL that is being run.

Comment: After you have printed the SQL, isolate the file that cause the issue - are they the same files every time? That is two items of troubleshooting that you really should have done first.

Comment: I did that and seperated the files but I want to force them to upload. I can not find what is wrong with the files I have isolated.

Comment: Try opening them in a test editor that shows hidden characters (i.e. Visual Stusio Code). Try removing records and see if it helps. You need to work out what wrong with them before they'll insert